# Global array -- no need for "global" statement

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this code:

```
sample_array = ones ([N, 3], dtype = float)
def get_training_set ():
    r = rand (N, 2) * 2 - 1
    sample_array[:,[0,1]] = r
    return sample_array
```

I declared the sampling array outside, in order not to allocate it all the time, just to modify it -- the last coordinate is always 1.

Initially I expected that I have to insert a statement "global sample_array" in function, because I modify it, and consequently the evaluator should know that it's a global var.

But, to my surprise, it works well without "global". *Why does it work ?* Where/what is the definition of evaluation in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` is necessary if you are changing the reference to an object (e.g. with an assignment).  It is *not* necessary if you are just mutating the object (e.g. with slice assignment like what you've done above).

The exact documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt).

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

So, with the global statement, you're telling python that the variable lives in the global context.  If you assign to it, then you change the value in the global context.

If you don't use the global statement, python decides whether the variable is local or nonlocal.  (In fact, python3.x added a `nonlocal` keyword).  The variable is nonlocal if it appears first on the right side of an assignment, or if you do item assignment (`x[...] = ...`) or attribute assignment (`x.whatever = ...`).  If the variable is local, that means that it was created in the function (or is an input argument).  You can reassign directly to a local identifier and there's no problem.  If the variable is non-local, you can mutate it, but you can't re-assign it because then python is unable to determine whether the variable is local or non-local.

Comment: Good. Can you show me the official manual/definition explaining this ?

Comment: @alinsoar mutation is when you change something `in place`, which is exactly what you're doing. You'd need a `global` statement if you defined something **in** the function, didn't return it, and then were referring to it **outside** that function.

Comment: @mgilson. I know what means global. However, I see no direct definition about what happens with the mutable variables.

Comment: @Aleksander -- why the mutable var that changes need no "global" statement? Can you see this in the manual ?

Comment: @alinsoar -- It's a matter of scope.  Python picks the object up from the outer scope.  Since you have a reference to the object, you can mutate it.  (You can always mutate mutable objects -- It'd be silly if there were circumstances where you couldn't.  Then they'd be sorta-mutable objects).

Comment: @mgilson I think I understand . I sees "sample_array[:,[0,1]] = ,,," as an assignment to a pointer somewhere, and this is not an object from the closure of an envinronment, but a location of memeory, so consequently it does not need to know how to search it in closures, etc. You give it directly the location. Hence, no need to tell it a characteristic of the LEFT side.

Comment: clear, thanks. However, nowhere in the manual was specified literaly. You need to find it out by mistake :).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because sample_array is not declared inside the function, but just write.
Python cannot find sample_array in side function namespace, it will find the outer namespace.
E.g.

```
a = []

def test1():
    a.append(1)  # will use the outer one

def test2():
    a = []
    a.append(1)  # will use the inner one
```

Global, sometimes, for declare a global variable:

```
def declare_global():
  global b  # this should be global after 'declare_global()' is called
  b = 1

print b  # raise NameError: name 'b' is not defined
declare_global()
print b  # will output '1'
```

Comment: I think my problem is a little different ;) It is about mutable variable , that are treated differently than a normal var.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get the poing >_<

Comment: should be `a.append(1)` -- parenthesis, not `[]`

Comment: @alinsoar -- And, for what it's worth, your problem is no different than the first example here.  `a` is declared outside the function and mutated inside the function.  You declare `sample_array` outside and mutate it inside a function.  Exactly the same.